# Using the factor theorem, show that $x+3$ is a factor of $y(x)$ in the polynomial $y(x)=x^3 + 5x^2 + 8x + 6$

Tags: linear-algebra

Considering the cubic polynomial

$$y(x)=x^3 + 5x^2 + 8x + 6,$$

show that $x+3$ is a factor of $y(x)$ using the factor theorem.

Sorry, I'm a bit stuck with this question. Would you use long division? Or would that be for the second part of the question where I have to fully factorise $y(x)$ and hence show that $x=−3$ is the only real zero of $y(x)$.?

Comment: Show that $y(-3)=0$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factor_theorem

Comment: As suggested, show $y(-3)=0$. This will imply that $x+3$ is a factor of $y(x)$. Then do polynomial long division as you suggest and find the roots of the quadratic if you're asked to factorise $y(x)$, i.e. find all the roots.

Answer (score 2):

If $x+3$ is a factor, this means that:
$$x^3+5x^2+8x+6=(x+3)(\text{some quadratic})$$
From this you can take from what you already know that when $x=-3$, $y(x)=0$

So plug $-3$ into your equation for:
$$(-3)^3+5(-3)^2+8(-3)+6$$
$$\to -27+45-24+6$$
$$\to -51+51$$
$$\to 0$$
and therefore it is a factor.

With regards to the second part, you have to find the thing I've labelled "$(\text{some quadratic})$"

Use that:
$$(x+3)(Ax^2+Bx+C)=x^3+5x^2+8x+6$$expand and compare to see that:
$$Ax^3=x^3\to A=1$$
$$3Ax^2+Bx^2=5x^2\to B=2$$
$$3Bx+Cx=8x\to C=2$$
$$3C=6\to C=2\space \text{(confirmation)}$$

Thus:
$$(x+3)(x^2+2x+2)=x^3+5x^2+8x+6$$In order to show that $x=-3$ is the only real root, prove that the roots of $x^2+2x+2$ are not real. We use the *discriminant* $D=B^2-4AC$ for this. If there are no real roots, then $D<0$ (the reason why this is true is due to the quadratic formula: $x=\frac{-B\pm\sqrt{D}}{2A}$, we cannot square root a negative value and expect a real answer
. Hence check this:
$$B^2-4AC\to 2^2-4(1)(2)\to 4-8\to -4<0$$ which therefore means it has no real roots.

Answer (score 1):

Since $x+3$ is a factor of $y(x)$

$y(-3)=0$
$$(-3)^3+5(-3)^2+8(-3)+6=0$$
$$-27+45-24+6=0$$
$$0=0$$
Hence $x+3$ is a factor of $y(x)$